# Query and exclude softwares installed on remote computers

Tags: powershell

I'm using the following powershell function to list the software installed on remote computers and export the data into various formats such as CSV, GridView or console :

```
Function Get-InstalledApplication
{
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
[string[]]$Computername,
[String[]]$OutputType,
[string[]]$outpath
)

#Registry Hives

$Object =@()

$excludeArray = ("Security Update for Windows",
"Update for Windows",
"Update for Microsoft .NET",
"Security Update for Microsoft",
"Hotfix for Windows",
"Hotfix for Microsoft .NET Framework",
"Hotfix for Microsoft Visual Studio 2007 Tools",
"Microsoft Visual C++ 2010",
"cwbin64a",
"Hotfix")

[long]$HIVE_HKROOT = 2147483648
[long]$HIVE_HKCU = 2147483649
[long]$HIVE_HKLM = 2147483650
[long]$HIVE_HKU = 2147483651
[long]$HIVE_HKCC = 2147483653
[long]$HIVE_HKDD = 2147483654

Foreach($EachServer in $Computername){
$Query = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Computername -query "Select AddressWidth, DataWidth,Architecture from Win32_Processor" 
foreach ($i in $Query)
{
 If($i.AddressWidth -eq 64){            
 $OSArch='64-bit'
 }            
Else{            
$OSArch='32-bit'            
}
}

Switch ($OSArch)
{

 "64-bit"{
$RegProv = GWMI -Namespace "root\Default" -list -computername $EachServer| where{$_.Name -eq "StdRegProv"}
$Hive = $HIVE_HKLM
$RegKey_64BitApps_64BitOS = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
$RegKey_32BitApps_64BitOS = "Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
$RegKey_32BitApps_32BitOS = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

#############################################################################

# Get SubKey names

$SubKeys = $RegProv.EnumKey($HIVE, $RegKey_64BitApps_64BitOS)

# Make Sure No Error when Reading Registry

if ($SubKeys.ReturnValue -eq 0)
{  # Loop through all returned subkeys
ForEach ($Name in $SubKeys.sNames)
 {
$SubKey = "$RegKey_64BitApps_64BitOS\$Name"
$ValueName = "DisplayName"
$ValuesReturned = $RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, $SubKey, $ValueName)
$AppName = $ValuesReturned.sValue
$Version = ($RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, $SubKey, "DisplayVersion")).sValue 
$Publisher = ($RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, $SubKey, "Publisher")).sValue 
$donotwrite = $false

if($AppName.length -gt "0"){

 Foreach($exclude in $excludeArray) 
                        {
                        if($AppName.StartsWith($exclude) -eq $TRUE)
                            {
                            $donotwrite = $true
                            break
                            }
                        }
            if ($donotwrite -eq $false) 
                        {                        
            $Object += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Application = $AppName;
            Architecture  = "64-BIT";
            ServerName = $EachServer;
            Version = $Version;
            Publisher= $Publisher;
           }
                        }

}

  }}

#############################################################################

$SubKeys = $RegProv.EnumKey($HIVE, $RegKey_32BitApps_64BitOS)

# Make Sure No Error when Reading Registry

if ($SubKeys.ReturnValue -eq 0)

{

  # Loop Through All Returned SubKEys

  ForEach ($Name in $SubKeys.sNames)

  {

    $SubKey = "$RegKey_32BitApps_64BitOS\$Name"

$ValueName = "DisplayName"
$ValuesReturned = $RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, $SubKey, $ValueName)
$AppName = $ValuesReturned.sValue
$Version = ($RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, $SubKey, "DisplayVersion")).sValue 
$Publisher = ($RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, $SubKey, "Publisher")).sValue 
 $donotwrite = $false

if($AppName.length -gt "0"){
 Foreach($exclude in $excludeArray) 
                        {
                        if($AppName.StartsWith($exclude) -eq $TRUE)
                            {
                            $donotwrite = $true
                            break
                            }
                        }
            if ($donotwrite -eq $false) 
                        {                        
            $Object += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Application = $AppName;
            Architecture  = "32-BIT";
            ServerName = $EachServer;
            Version = $Version;
            Publisher= $Publisher;
           }
                        }
           }

    }

}

} #End of 64 Bit

######################################################################################

###########################################################################################

"32-bit"{

$RegProv = GWMI -Namespace "root\Default" -list -computername $EachServer| where{$_.Name -eq "StdRegProv"}

$Hive = $HIVE_HKLM

$RegKey_32BitApps_32BitOS = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"

#############################################################################

# Get SubKey names

$SubKeys = $RegProv.EnumKey($HIVE, $RegKey_32BitApps_32BitOS)

# Make Sure No Error when Reading Registry

if ($SubKeys.ReturnValue -eq 0)

{  # Loop Through All Returned SubKEys

  ForEach ($Name in $SubKeys.sNames)

  {
$SubKey = "$RegKey_32BitApps_32BitOS\$Name"
$ValueName = "DisplayName"
$ValuesReturned = $RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, $SubKey, $ValueName)
$AppName = $ValuesReturned.sValue
$Version = ($RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, $SubKey, "DisplayVersion")).sValue 
$Publisher = ($RegProv.GetStringValue($Hive, $SubKey, "Publisher")).sValue 

if($AppName.length -gt "0"){

$Object += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            Application = $AppName;
            Architecture  = "32-BIT";
            ServerName = $EachServer;
            Version = $Version;
            Publisher= $Publisher;
           }
           }

  }}

}#End of 32 bit

} # End of Switch

}

#$AppsReport

$column1 = @{expression="ServerName"; width=15; label="Name"; alignment="left"}
$column2 = @{expression="Architecture"; width=10; label="32/64 Bit"; alignment="left"}
$column3 = @{expression="Application"; width=80; label="Application"; alignment="left"}
$column4 = @{expression="Version"; width=15; label="Version"; alignment="left"}
$column5 = @{expression="Publisher"; width=30; label="Publisher"; alignment="left"}

if ($outputType -eq "Console")
{
"#"*80
"Installed Software Application Report"
"Number of Installed Application count : $($object.count)"
"Generated $(get-date)"
"Generated from $(gc env:computername)"
"#"*80
$object |Format-Table $column1, $column2, $column3 ,$column4, $column5
}

elseif ($OutputType -eq "GridView")
{
$object|Out-GridView 
}
elseif ($OutputType -eq "CSV")
{
[string]$FileDS = Get-Date -Format "yyyyMMdd"
[string]$outFile = $outpath+'\'+$computername+'_'+$FileDS+'.csv'
New-Item -ItemType file $outfile -Force
$object | export-csv -path $outfile
}
else
{
write-host " Invalid Output Type $OutputType"
}


}
```

I'm also using the code to exclude some application from a list. I have a problem on PCs running a 32-bit version of Windows (tested on a 32-bit Windows 7) : applications excluded from this list still appear in the output. No problem on 64-bit systems however.

Ideas of what's wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: the 1st thing i would check it the exact text of the items in the 32bit `AppName` variable. also, it LOOKS like that will be an array of items ... so i would not expect that `.StartwWith()` string method to work at all. [*frown*]

Comment: Please reduce that wall of code to a [mcve]. We're not going to debug several hundred lines of poorly formatted code for you.

Comment: `StartsWith()` is case sensitive. You can make it case insensitive by using `StartsWith($exclude, [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` or better still use the `-like` or `-match` operators. Did you check the different appnames on a 32-bit machine? Are they the same as in 64-bit pc's?. Please also teach yourself to indent your code properly! (or is this _your_ code? I know for sure I saw it before..)

Comment: It's not my code. It's from someone on Technet. The appnames are mostly the same on both 32 and 64-bit pc's. For example, the "Security Update for Microsoft ..." are well excluded on the 64-bit but not on the 32.